# '+' in url query string is lost during model binding in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My URL has a query string parameter like:

```
serializedSelectedRefiners=sgAAAB+LCAAAAAAABACLrlZKLCkpykwqLUn1S8xNVbJSKs7ILCjIzEvXKy5JLElV0kEoCEvMKQWpcHZUqtXB1JiUmZMD0pecWVKJTVtwZnpeYo6CB1AZXv147Y0FAOGK0ziyAAAA
```

The problem is that the `+` in this query string parameter is lost in the model binding process. So after model binding, it looks like:

```
VM.serializedSelectedRefiners =  sgAAABLCAAAAAAABACLrlZKLCkpykwqLUn1S8xNVbJSKs7ILCjIzEvXKy5JLElV0kEoCEvMKQWpcHZUqtXB1JiUmZMD0pecWVKJTVtwZnpeYo6CB1AZXv147Y0FAOGK0ziyAAAA
```

Note the absense of `+` after `sgAAAB`.
Can someone explain the reason for this?

Comment: I'm guessing it is translated to a space character. This is because `+` is a special character in query parameters (It represents a space). You'll want to URL encode your query parameter to make sure pluses are converted to `%2B` which will be appropriately parsed on the server side.

Comment: that, encode the whole string, or use the escape sequence for it (I don't know it off hand, but there is one!)

Answer (score 0):

Marc's answer is correct. It works after I URL encoded the query parameter.